# ARCGIS Attribute Editing at RunTime Using Javascript API

Tags: javascript, dojo, esri, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-runtime

Currently I am building a web Application using `ArcGIS Javascript API`.

Where I can add marker to the map graphics, on adding marker request I am setting few attributes to that marker using Popup Template like this

```
map.graphics.add(new Graphic(evt.geometry, symbol, PointAtt, popupTemplate));
```

Here I want to ask, how I can edit these attributes at Map Runtime because I want to do some changes in the attributes.

```
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.17/"></script>
    <script>
      var map, tb;
      var otherWindow;
      var PointAtt = {};
      require([
            "esri/map",
            "esri/toolbars/draw",
            "esri/dijit/PopupTemplate",
            "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol", "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
            "esri/symbols/PictureFillSymbol", "esri/symbols/CartographicLineSymbol",
            "esri/graphic",
            "esri/Color", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on",
            "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function (
            Map, Draw, PopupTemplate,
            SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol,
            PictureFillSymbol, CartographicLineSymbol,
            Graphic,
            Color, dom, on) {
        map = new Map("mapDiv", {
                basemap : "streets",
                center : [-25.312, 34.307],
                zoom : 3
            });

        otherWindow = window.open("integrationPage.html", "otherWindow");
        map.on("load", initToolbar);

        // markerSymbol is used for point and multipoint, see http://raphaeljs.com/icons/#talkq for more examples
        var markerSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol();
        markerSymbol.setPath("M16,4.938c-7.732,0-14,4.701-14,10.5c0,1.981,0.741,3.833,2.016,5.414L2,25.272l5.613-1.44c2.339,1.316,5.237,2.106,8.387,2.106c7.732,0,14-4.701,14-10.5S23.732,4.938,16,4.938zM16.868,21.375h-1.969v-1.889h1.969V21.375zM16.772,18.094h-1.777l-0.176-8.083h2.113L16.772,18.094z");
        markerSymbol.setColor(new Color("#00FFFF"));

        // lineSymbol used for freehand polyline, polyline and line.
        var lineSymbol = new CartographicLineSymbol(
                CartographicLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                new Color([255, 0, 0]), 10,
                CartographicLineSymbol.CAP_ROUND,
                CartographicLineSymbol.JOIN_MITER, 5);

        // fill symbol used for extent, polygon and freehand polygon, use a picture fill symbol
        // the images folder contains additional fill images, other options: sand.png, swamp.png or stiple.png
        var fillSymbol = new PictureFillSymbol(
                "images/mangrove.png",
                new SimpleLineSymbol(
                    SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                    new Color('#000'),
                    1),
                42,
                42);

        function initToolbar() {
            tb = new Draw(map);
            tb.on("draw-end", addGraphic);
            // Get Marker Click Event
            map.graphics.on("click", function (evt) {
                // alert("Marker Clicked");
                var lat = evt.mapPoint.getLatitude();
                var lon = evt.mapPoint.getLongitude();


                var sendEvent = [];
                sendEvent[0] = evt.graphic.attributes.ID;
                sendEvent[1] = evt.mapPoint.getLatitude();
                sendEvent[2] = evt.mapPoint.getLongitude();
                // Sending event to other html page
                otherWindow.postMessage(sendEvent, "http://localhost:9090");


            });
            // event delegation so a click handler is not
            // needed for each individual button
            on(dom.byId("info"), "click", function (evt) {
                if (evt.target.id === "info") {
                    return;
                }
                var tool = evt.target.id.toLowerCase();
                map.disableMapNavigation();
                tb.activate(tool);
            });
        }

        function addGraphic(evt) {
            // deactivate the toolbar and clear existing graphics
            tb.deactivate();
            map.enableMapNavigation();

            var sendEvent = []; // Array which is sent to other sources
            var counter = 0;
            sendEvent[0] = "added"
            sendEvent[1] = evt.geometry.getLatitude();
            sendEvent[2] = evt.geometry.getLongitude();


            otherWindow.postMessage(sendEvent, "http://localhost:9090");

            // Marker ID is being received from the Key Generator
            window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
                var receivedEvent;
                console.log("onMessage::" + event.data);
                receivedEvent = event.data;

                if (receivedEvent[0] == "added" && counter == 0) {
                    PointAtt = {
                        Name : "Islamabad", // The name of the pipeline
                        Type : "City", // The owner of the pipeline
                        ID : receivedEvent[1],// The length of the pipeline
                        Latitude : evt.geometry.getLatitude(),
                        Longitude: evt.geometry.getLongitude()
                    };
                    var popupTemplate = new PopupTemplate({
                            title : "{*}", // The title of the popup will be the name of the pipeline
                            content : "{*}" // Displays a table of all the attributes in the popup
                        })

                        // figure out which symbol to use
                        var symbol;
                    if (evt.geometry.type === "point" || evt.geometry.type === "multipoint") {
                        symbol = markerSymbol;
                    } else if (evt.geometry.type === "line" || evt.geometry.type === "polyline") {
                        symbol = lineSymbol;
                    } else {
                        symbol = fillSymbol;
                    }
                    map.graphics.add(new Graphic(evt.geometry, symbol, PointAtt, popupTemplate));
                    counter = counter + 1;
                    event.data = "";
                }

            }, false);

        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ***`esri AttributeInspector`*** for this. Though it works for feature layers to but you can customize it accordingly.

***Either*** you can create feature layer on the map and add graphics to it and pass that to `layerInfos` **OR** you can override the attribute inspector so support graphics layer too.

Use Below code for this-

```
 //add a save button next to the delete button
      var saveButton = new Button({ label: "Save", "class": "saveButton"},domConstruct.create("div"));
      domConstruct.place(saveButton.domNode, attInspector.deleteBtn.domNode, "after");

      saveButton.on("click", function() {
        updateFeature.getLayer().applyEdits(null, [updateFeature], null);
      });

      attInspector.on("attribute-change", function(evt) {
        //store the updates to apply when the save button is clicked
        updateFeature.attributes[evt.fieldName] = evt.fieldValue;
      });

      attInspector.on("next", function(evt) {
        updateFeature = evt.feature;
        console.log("Next " + updateFeature.attributes.OBJECTID);
      });
```

For attribute inspector [please click here...](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/attributeinspector-amd.html#attributeinspector1)

***Here is the working code for feature layer-***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>Editable FeatureLayer with Attribute Inspector</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/esri/css/esri.css">
<style>
  html, body, #mapDiv{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #detailPane{
    padding: 6px;
    height:20px;
    color:#570026;
    font-size:12pt;
    font-weight:600;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .dj_ie .infowindow .window .top .right .user .content { position: relative; }
  .dj_ie .simpleInfoWindow .content {position: relative;}

  .esriAttributeInspector .atiLayerName {display:none;}
</style>

<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/"></script>
<script>
  var map, updateFeature;

  require([
    "esri/map",
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
    "esri/dijit/AttributeInspector",

    "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
    "esri/Color",
    "esri/renderers/UniqueValueRenderer",

    "esri/config",

    "esri/tasks/query",
    "dojo/dom-construct",
    "dijit/form/Button",

    "dojo/domReady!"
  ], function(
    Map, FeatureLayer, AttributeInspector,
    SimpleLineSymbol, SimpleMarkerSymbol, Color, UniqueValueRenderer,
    esriConfig,
    Query, domConstruct, Button
  ) {
    // refer to "Using the Proxy Page" for more information:  https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/ags_proxy.html
    esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/proxy/";

    map = new Map("mapDiv", {
      basemap: "dark-gray",
      center: [-97.395, 37.537],
      zoom: 5
    });

    map.on("layers-add-result", initSelectToolbar);

    //Feature Layer representing 2015 men's NCAA basketball tournament teams
    var teamsFL = new FeatureLayer("https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/NCAA_Tourney_2015/FeatureServer/1", {
      outFields: ["University", "WINPER", "Rd_64_Venue", "Rd_64_Result", "Rd_64_Margin"]
    });

    var selectionSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(
        SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE, 6,
        new SimpleLineSymbol(
            "solid",
            new Color([255,0,0,0.5]),
            4
        ),
        new Color("#ED3939")
    );

    var defaultSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(
        SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE, 7,
        null,
        new Color([255,255,255])
    );
    teamsFL.setSelectionSymbol(selectionSymbol);

    //Symbolize features by W/L record
    var recordRenderer = new UniqueValueRenderer(defaultSymbol, "Rd_64_Result");
    recordRenderer.addValue("W", new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE, 7, null, new Color([93,240,79])));
    recordRenderer.addValue("L", new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE, 7, null, new Color([240,146,79])));
    teamsFL.setRenderer(recordRenderer);

    map.addLayers([teamsFL]);

    function initSelectToolbar(evt) {
      var teamsFL = evt.layers[0].layer;
      var selectQuery = new Query();

      map.on("click", function(evt) {
        selectQuery.geometry = evt.mapPoint;
        selectQuery.distance = 50;
        selectQuery.units = "miles"
        selectQuery.returnGeometry = true;
        teamsFL.selectFeatures(selectQuery, FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW, function(features) {
          if (features.length > 0) {
            //store the current feature
            updateFeature = features[0];
            map.infoWindow.setTitle(features[0].getLayer().name);
            map.infoWindow.show(evt.screenPoint, map.getInfoWindowAnchor(evt.screenPoint));
          }
          else {
            map.infoWindow.hide();
          }
        });
      });

      map.infoWindow.on("hide", function() {
        teamsFL.clearSelection();
      });

      var layerInfos = [
        {
          'featureLayer': teamsFL,
          'showAttachments': false,
          'isEditable': true,
          'fieldInfos': [
            {'fieldName': 'University', 'isEditable': false, 'label': 'School:'},
            {'fieldName': 'WINPER', 'isEditable': true, 'tooltip': 'Win percentage', 'label': 'Win percentage:'},
            {'fieldName': 'Rd_64_Venue', 'isEditable': false, 'label': 'Rd 1 Venue:'},
            {'fieldName': 'Rd_64_Result', 'isEditable': true, 'tooltip': 'First round result (W/L)', 'label': 'Rd 1 Result:'},
            {'fieldName': 'Rd_64_Margin', 'isEditable': true, 'tooltip': 'First round margin of victory/loss', 'label': 'Rd 1 Margin:'}
          ]
        }
      ];

      //Initialize Attribute Inspector
      var attInspector = new AttributeInspector({
        layerInfos: layerInfos
      }, domConstruct.create("div"));

      //add a save button next to the delete button
      var saveButton = new Button({ label: "Save", "class": "saveButton"},domConstruct.create("div"));
      domConstruct.place(saveButton.domNode, attInspector.deleteBtn.domNode, "after");

      saveButton.on("click", function() {
        updateFeature.getLayer().applyEdits(null, [updateFeature], null);
      });

      attInspector.on("attribute-change", function(evt) {
        //store the updates to apply when the save button is clicked
        updateFeature.attributes[evt.fieldName] = evt.fieldValue;
      });

      attInspector.on("next", function(evt) {
        updateFeature = evt.feature;
        console.log("Next " + updateFeature.attributes.OBJECTID);
      });

      attInspector.on("delete", function(evt) {
        evt.feature.getLayer().applyEdits(null, null, [evt.feature]);
        map.infoWindow.hide();
      });

      map.infoWindow.setContent(attInspector.domNode);
      map.infoWindow.resize(350, 240);
    }
  });
</script>
</head>

<body class="claro">
  <div id="detailPane">
    Click to display the attribute inspector for all NCAA men's basketball tournament teams within 50 miles of click.
  </div>
  <div id="mapDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

***Output:-***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, It seems quite straight forward to implement. You can use ***setter*** method of attribute for it. It will direct update the existing ***`attributes/Values`*** of feature on the map.

Use Below code for it-

```
var attributeObject = {"name":"updatedNmme","value":"updatedValue"};
graphicsObject.setAttributes(attributeObject );
```

***Note-*** It will remove all the existing attributes and add new attributes(***`attributeObject`*** ) to the graphics so if you want to keep some of the existing attributes as it is then pass those values also in  ***`attributeObject.`***

For complete reference [please click here...](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/graphic-amd.html#setattributes)

***Hoping this will help you :)***

**P.S.** *It is always recommended to add complete code here if you are expecting the exact fix. However above code will fix your problem.*

Comment: Thanks, Buddy for quick reply, Here is my complete code:

Comment: I have pasted the updated code, here at Map runtime when map loads and i can add markers to the map, on each marker addition i can set the attributes at it and when i click on that marker these attributes displayed on popup.
Here

Comment: Continue....
Here I want that to edit these attributes on the popup and after edition i want to save them and on next click i want to see these updated values.

Comment: Well this kind of behavior is used mainly when we load feature on the map using a feature layer(Editable map servers)... I will try to create a sample on graphics to asap...

Comment: Please can you guide me in that direction how i can achieve that behaviour. If you can refer any link, tutorial i will help me greatly.

Comment: can you tell me exactly what you want to update in attribute...?